# Setting Content-Transfer-Encoding header using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, http, web

I'm looking to see if the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header can be set for a `multipart/form-data` HTTP request in JavaScript especially for a file upload request.

I came across the [Blob API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) which the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) extends and I can set the `Content-Type` header like,

```
var file1 = File(['file1_contents'], 'filename1', {type : 'application/json'});
```

But I can't seem to set the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header.

So, can it be set using JavaScript. If not why not?

Comment: isn't `Content-Transfer-Encoding` an email header? what does that have to do with  javascript, html, or http

Comment: If you're really asking about the `Transfer-Encoding` header, that is **response** header, so is only relevant in http responses

Comment: @JaromandaX I guess your earlier response makes sense. [Content-Transfer-Encoding](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html) header is indeed for emails and perhaps that's why browsers don't support it?